# Using R, data.table, rename a subset of columns by column names instead of positions

Tags: r, data.table, names

I have a data table similar to this except much larger:

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(t1=round(rnorm(5),1), t2=round(rnorm(5),1), t3=round(rnorm(5),1), 
             t4=round(rnorm(5),1), t5=round(rnorm(5),1), t6=round(rnorm(5),1),
             t7=round(rnorm(5),1),t8=round(rnorm(5),1))
```

Which outputs:

```
     t1   t2   t3  t4   t5   t6   t7   t8
 1: -0.6 -0.8  1.5 0.0  0.9 -0.1  1.4 -0.4
 2:  0.2  0.5  0.4 0.0  0.8 -0.2 -0.1 -0.4
 3: -0.8  0.7 -0.6 0.9  0.1 -1.5  0.4 -0.1
 4:  1.6  0.6 -2.2 0.8 -2.0 -0.5 -0.1  1.1
 5:  0.3 -0.3  1.1 0.6  0.6  0.4 -1.4  0.8
```

I would like to rename columns t3:t8 as hour_t3:hour_t8, to output like this:

```
     t1   t2 hour_t3 hour_t4 hour_t5 hour_t6 hour_t7 hour_t8
 1: -0.6 -0.8     1.5     0.0     0.9    -0.1     1.4    -0.4
 2:  0.2  0.5     0.4     0.0     0.8    -0.2    -0.1    -0.4
 3: -0.8  0.7    -0.6     0.9     0.1    -1.5     0.4    -0.1
 4:  1.6  0.6    -2.2     0.8    -2.0    -0.5    -0.1     1.1
 5:  0.3 -0.3     1.1     0.6     0.6     0.4    -1.4     0.8
```

These two methods work:

```
names(dt)[3:8] <- c(paste0("hour_t", 3:8))
```

and

```
setnames(dt, 3:8, c(paste0("hour_t", 3:8)))
```

but, I would like to be able to subset by reference using something like this:

```
setnames(dt, "t3":"t8", c(paste0("hour_t", 3:8)))
```

When I use such syntax or subset with c("t3":"t8"), I get the following error:

```
Error in "t3":"t8" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In setnames(dt, c("t3":"t8"), c(paste0("hour_t", 3:8))) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In setnames(dt, c("t3":"t8"), c(paste0("hour_t", 3:8))) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any thoughts on how to subset the columns to rename by reference/column name instead of by position would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

I am still quite new to data.table and am using data.table version 1.9.6.

Comment: `setnames(dt, paste0("t", 3:8), paste0("hour_t", 3:8))`.... read `?setnames` more carefully

Comment: Thinking again, maybe easier to parse visually: `cols <- paste0("t", 3:8); setnames(dt, cols, paste0("hour_", cols))`

Comment: Because `"t3":"t8"` is meaningless, as the error message is telling you. But `paste0("t", 3:8)` works. @MichaelChirico please post that as an answer!